# Cannot change div background color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the background color for my div's with the class "box" with javascript on page load. I am changing the document with getElementsByClassName, but when I load the page nothing happens. I've checked for typos and researched the internet, but really cannot figure this one out...and it's so simple too.

Please help

```js
window.onload = function changeDivColor () {
  document.getElementsByClassName("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
};
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet"
  type="text/css"
  href="/Users/skyler/Documents/GitHub/Code/style.css"/>

<script src="javascript.js"> </script>



  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"> <label> <input type="checkbox"> <div class="label-text"></div> </label> </div>
    
  </div>
  
</html>
```

Comment: There are answers already but in future if you get stuck anywhere like this you can try console logging and see what exactly you are accessing and if you are doing it right by using  like `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("box"))` for above example.

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementsByClassName` return an array, you need get index 0 for first item

```
document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

```js
window.onload = function changeDivColor () {
  document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
};
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet"
  type="text/css"
  href="/Users/skyler/Documents/GitHub/Code/style.css"/>

<script src="javascript.js"> </script>



  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"> <label> <input type="checkbox"> <div class="label-text"></div> </label> </div>
    
  </div>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively You can use `querySelector` to get the first element with that class

```
window.onload = function changeDivColor () {
    document.querySelector(".box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. The method
`getElementsByClassName` returns an array, so you have to target the index of the element you want to manipulate. In this case this should work:

```
window.onload = function changeDivColor () {
 document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
window.onload = function changeDivColor () {
  document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
};
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet"
  type="text/css"
  href="/Users/skyler/Documents/GitHub/Code/style.css"/>

<script src="javascript.js"> </script>



  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"> <label> <input type="checkbox"> <div class="label-text"></div> </label> </div>

  </div>

</html>
```